# controller_interface frequency rate

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using  the ros_control interface to implement a position controller to use both in Simulation (Gazebo)
and on a real robot. My implementation inherits from control_base.h and I implement **hardware_interface::PositionJointInterface**.

**My problem** is that I would like to know the **frequency of the update rate** (base class code shown below) such to perform interpolation between desired and target joint positions such to follow a desired velocity.

```
 /// Calls \ref update only if this controller is running.
 void updateRequest(const ros::Time& time, const ros::Duration& period)
{
if (state_ == RUNNING)
  update(time, period);
 }
```

Is there a method that gives me back the update rate of this function (above). Is it in the Time and Duration variables ?
I have so fare failed to find a good tutorial which explains in detail the usage of control_base.h etc.. any pointers
would be welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222303/controller_interface-frequency-rate/) by [gpldecha](https://answers.ros.org/users/20741/gpldecha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2015-12-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-10**:
I may be misunderstanding you, but isn't `period` the inverse of what you are asking?

**Comment by [gpldecha](https://answers.ros.org/users/20741/gpldecha/) on 2015-12-10**:
yes, it is have just figured it out.. was not use to using ros::time and ros::Duration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Simply can get the frequency by doing period.toSec();

---

Originally posted by [gpldecha](https://answers.ros.org/users/20741/gpldecha/) with karma: 285 on 2015-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0